# Jacket mesh not following rig

Tags: rigging

fairly new to blender. I have a jacket mesh I am trying add a rig to, in order import the mesh as an UMA recipe in Unity. The mesh have had weight transferred and I have added the rig as a modifier and it is activated. However when I try to animate the arm the mesh won't follow the bones. I am not trying to add the animation to the blender file, just testing to see if it follows the rig (which it doesn't) I am also attaching the blender file. What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to add an armature modifier to the jacket (mesh_1) and fix the weight painting.

Comment: I added the armature and did not apply it, I then went back into weight painting mode and painted the entire mesh (I guess I missed this step). However when I transfer weight only left arm is added to the vertex groups, however at least when I move that arm the jacket follow, however it doesn't stick to the rest of the body. How do I add all vertexes (I selected By Name) in the little box down below to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the jacket, delete all its vertex groups (*Delete All Groups*), give it the *Data Trasfer* modifier, choose the *Source* (which is *UMA_Human_Male_Torso*), enable *Vertex Data*, under *Vertex Data* click on *Vertex Groups*, click on *Generate Data Layers*, apply the modifier. Give your jacket an *Armature* modifier, choose the armature called *UMA_Male_Rig* as *Object*, it should work (it probably needs a bit of weight painting):

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for you answer, this fixed the issue with the jacket not sticking to the bones, I guess it was the data transfer step I missed.